# jquery remove div inside of other divs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a main `<div>` with many other divs inside like this:

[HTML]

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class ="deleteMe">
       delete me 
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

I want to remove the div with class name "deleteMe", i tried to remove it by using ,find() method from jquery:

```
$('.container').find('.row').find('.col').find('deleteMe').remove();
```

or

```
$('.container').find('.row').find('.col').removeClass('.deleteMe');
```

But didn't work, what is the best way to remove it?

here is the fiddle link test this exemple:

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pratykus/e3m60ytn/5/)

```js
//$('.container').find('.row').find('.col').find('deleteMe').remove();

$('.container').find('.row').find('.col').removeClass('.deleteMe');
```

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}

.deleteMe {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- 
  Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs
-->

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="deleteMe">
        delete me
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if you want to remove the class, you do not need the dot. `$('.container').find('.row').find('.col').find('.deleteMe').removeClass('deleteMe');` if you want to remove the div, you need `$('.container').find('.row').find('.col').find('.deleteMe').remove()` or just `$('.container .deleteMe').remove()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need jquery for the job, see the following code snippet ( The `setTimeout` wrapper delays the deletion by 1s and only serves to see what is happening.

```js
setTimeout ( () => {
    document.querySelector(".deleteMe").remove();
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class ="deleteMe">
       delete me 
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Given your original code, you might want the selector to be more specific:

```
 document.querySelector(".container > .row > .col > .deleteMe").remove(); // Adjacent sub-selectors reference elements in a parent/child relation      
 document.querySelector(".container .row .col .deleteMe").remove(); // The elements are in a ancestor/descendant relation, not necessarily child/parent
```

Comment: You can do almost everything without jquery with same number of rows. VanillaJS is the best :)

Comment: @Zoldszemesostoros Yes, since the browsers have matured and some abomIEnations have effectively retired ... ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 $(".container .deleteMe").remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

below line will do

```
$( ".container .row .col .deleteMe" ).remove();
```

Comment: It isn't if only `.deleteMe` elements with `.col` and `.row` ancestors are to be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

There is a little typo in your code: a . is missing before `deleteMe`.

```
$('.container').find('.row').find('.col').find('.deleteMe').remove();
```

correctly.
Another thing: `removeClass` don't remove an element with the specified class; It removes the specified class from the element.